# Upsert with two external_id in APEX

Tags: salesforce-id, upsert, external

I can upsert objects with one external_id like below:

```
upsert objects external_id_a;
```

But I want to upsert with two external_id like

```
upsert objects external_id_a external_id_b;
```

But It's wrong syntax. So how can I do that?

Comment: What is the reason that you want to upsert using multiple external Ids? (In short its not possible but if you give us business use-case then someone here might be able to give you a workaround).

Comment: Because if I use only 1 existing external_id, it will be duplicated record and I want a new external_id pair to be able to solve it @Mahmood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer: It's not possible to `Upsert` using multiple external ids**

**Workaround**
Upsert using single ExternalID won't be duplicated if you created the ext id field with [unique constraint](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385174&type=1).

> External IDs are often created with the 'Unique ID' setting so that
> the External IDs will be unique to each record.

And if you are looking to make a compound key by concatenating 2 external ids, external_id_a & external_id_b, then you need to

1. create another text field as external Id with unique constraint
2. then use record-triggered flow to enter the value of both `external_Id_a` and `external_id_b` in that field.
3. finally, you'll have a field with merged value as extId1-extId2 which you can later use in Apex Upsert.

Comment: That's working!. Thank you so much @Mahmood